# DjangoAdmin: POST data is empty when saving a model with a filefield

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

My application has been setup on AWS lambda, together with API gateway, S3, cloudfront, RDS.

I'm having some troubles saving my model in DjangoAdmin that makes use of imagefield or filefields.

For some reason, when I submit my model, my POST data is empty.

This problem only comes forward upon saving a model that has a Filefield or Imagefield and when working online. So on localhost this isn't a problem at all and I can save images to my S3 bucket without a problem.

The reason why I found out is because I got a csrftoken is missing error at first.
So I made a custom csrf error view and printed out the request.POST data, where my csrfmiddleware token should be in.

Any ideas why this only happens when I have a filefield or imagefield in my model?

**EDIT:** Like previous said, I'm working with DjangoAdmin. So no custom forms... below is my very simple model...

Model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('image')
        verbose_name_plural = _('images')
```

Admin:

```
@admin.register(models.Image)
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'image']
```

Comment: Please add the form and related code to your question to find out the probable cause.

Comment: Like I said, I'm working with DjangoAdmin, so there is no custom form.. just a plain model  with a filefield in it..

Comment: "and printed out the request.POST data". You have to look in `request.FILES` for any uploaded files, and make sure that the `<form>` tag has the attribute `enctype=”multipart/form-data”`

Comment: @kunambi request.FILES and request.POST are both empty, my form is autogenerated by DjangoAdmin.. and when I look at it with the inspector, it does have that attribute

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the standard registration of your model?
your **admin.py** should look something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Image

admin.site.register(Image)
```

with this edit your code runs perfectly

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried that but still no luck.

Comment: I suggest recreating the app... something might went wrong while creating the app

Comment: Sadly, this is the route I had to take, but fortunately my app is now up and running :)